# How to read a value from a ros message?

Tags: ros, rosmessage, rostopic-echo, cmvision, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends,

I am new in ROS, I am usinig CMVISION package, and the tos topic which I need is " /blobs ", with type "cmvision/blobs"

$ rosmsg show cmvision/Blob

uint32 red
uint32 green
uint32 blue
uint32 area
uint32 x
uint32 y
uint32 left
uint32 right
uint32 top
uint32 bottom

I want to just read the "x", and "y" from this message,

As far as I know the "/" can help me, but I tried "rostopic echo /blobs/x" and it did not work....

Any body knows how I could do this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158976/how-to-read-a-value-from-a-ros-message?/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2014-04-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jacco van der Spek](https://answers.ros.org/users/15321/jacco-van-der-spek/) on 2014-04-29**:
Do you want to read the value in terminal or use it in your code?

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-04-30**:
I want to use that in another code to be the input,

**Comment by [abtin](https://answers.ros.org/users/53254/abtin/) on 2020-05-17**:
May you please say your solution for use in terminal , also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message that is being send over the topic is of type Blob.

You need to receive the message type Blob by subscribing to the topic.
Then in your code you can write something like

```
int x = blob_message.x;
int y = blob_message.y;
```

So in summary you need to receive the complete message.

---

Originally posted by [Jacco van der Spek](https://answers.ros.org/users/15321/jacco-van-der-spek/) with karma: 36 on 2014-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-04-30**:
Thanks a lot